# What is the purpose and utility of the subok option in numpy.zeros_like()?

Tags: python, class, numpy, subclass

Using numpy's [zeros_like](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html) and related functions, there is an option

> **subok:** bool, optional.
>
> `numpy.zeros_like(a, dtype=None, order='K', subok=True)`
>
> If True, then the newly created array will use the sub-class type of ‘a’, otherwise it will be a base-class array. Defaults to True.

I assumed all numpy arrays were of class `ndarray` and I've never had a need to look in detail at an array's *subclass*. Under what situations might I want to opt out of using the same subclass, specify the use of the base class?

Comment: ` np.matrix` and `MaskedArray` are `ndarray` subclasses

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for that; it's exactly what I needed to hear. I've never used either one for what I do, so it never occurred to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***What** is the **purpose** and **utility** ... ?*

### Purpose :

The call-signature **helps** either pass-through the processed instance-type, as seen here:

```
>>> np.array( np.mat( '1 2; 3 4' ),    # array-to-"process"
              subok = True             # FLAG True to ["pass-through"] the type
              )
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])                       # RESULT is indeed the instance of matrix
```

On the contrary, if not willing to "reprocess" both the `.shape` and instantiate the same class, using **`subok = False`**, the produced `*_alike()` will not get the same class, as the "example" the process was given to make the `*_alike()`-generated output:

```
type(                np.mat( '1 2;3 4' ) )   # <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
type( np.array(      np.mat( '1 2;3 4' ) ) ) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type( np.zeros_like( np.mat( '1 2;3 4' ) ) ) # <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>

>>> np.zeros_like(   np.mat( '1 2;3 4' ), subok = True  )
matrix([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]])
>>> np.zeros_like(   np.mat( '1 2;3 4' ), subok = False )
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

---

### Utility :

These `subok`-flags are common in more `numpy` functions ( not only the `*_like()`-s, also in `np.array( ... )` ), for the very same purpose, as it is pretty useful for smart type-modifying code designs, where desired type of the product is known to the "generating"-process and the results are thus achieved without undue class-related overheads, if ex-post modifications were needed otherwise.

Comment: Oh this is a wonderful answer; thank you for taking the time to explain in detail! Now I will read it thoroughly and see what I can learn.